# Get the first row in case when statement condition mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

**User_company**

```
user_id.       c_id       
11               1
12               2
13               3
14               4
15               4
```

**User_Company_fields**

```
User_id    Company_id     field id 
 11            1              6
 11            1              7
 13            3              1
 13            3              6
 13            3              4
 14            4              1 
 15            4              1
```

what I want is to combine the two tables with a condition that if the field id is 1 it should return the user_id and company_id with the options field as 1. If the user doesn't have the field id 1 (as user_id = 12) it should return 'not given' under field. If the user does have some other field than 1, it should again return 1 under field
What my end table should look like

```
User_id     company_id       field 
11               1          not given
12               2          not given 
13               3             1
14               4             1
15               4             1
```

What I am doing right now is returning this table

```
   User_id     company_id       field 
    11               1          not given
    11               1          not given
    12               2          not given 
    13               3             1
    14               4             1
    15               4             1
```

I want to return just one row for user id 11, instead of two. My case query is

```
select uc.user_id, uc.c_id, case when ucf.field_id = 1 then '1' when ucf.field_id is null then 'Not given' when ucf.field_id!= 1 then 'Not given' end as 'field' from user_company uc left join user_company_field ucf on uc.user_id = ucf.user_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close.

```
SELECT
  uc.user_id, 
  uc.c_id, 
  IF(MIN(ucf.field_id) = 1, '1', 'Not given') as 'field' 
FROM user_company uc 
  LEFT JOIN user_company_field ucf ON uc.user_id = ucf.user_id
GROUP BY uc.user_id, uc.c_id
```

Since you only care about `field_id` being 1, there is really no need for `CASE`. However, if you need more than two outcomes, then `CASE` is the way to go. I'm guessing that `field_id` is a FK, so there shouldn't be a risk of `field_id` being 0 and calling `MIN` on that field is 'safe'.

[Here is the demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/POl607jQ).